# JDBC PreparedStatement call within another JDBC PreparedStatement Connection Leak?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-leaks

I have some code I'm maintaining that makes an embedded JDBC call within another. This smells wrong to me but more importantly I'm wondering if this will cause a connection leak?

```
public Table1 method1(){
    String query = "SELECT id1, id2 FROM table1";
    Table1 t1 = new Table();
    try (Connection masterDB = getConnection();
         PreparedStatement statement = masterDB.prepareStatement(query);
         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (result.next()) {
                t1.setEntry(method2(result.getInt("id1")));
            }
    }
    return t1;
  }

  public Table2 method2(){
    String query = "SELECT idA, idB FROM table2";
    Table2 t2 = new Table2();
    try (Connection masterDB = getConnection();
         PreparedStatement statement = masterDB.prepareStatement(query);
         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (result.next()) {
                t2.setId((result.getInt("idA")));
            }
    }
    return t2;
  }
```

Comment: No, how would it do that?

Comment: Since `method2()` is called within a loop, it can be a bit un-optimal (depending on the size of result set in the first method) because each iteration retrieved a connection and prepares a statement. But because try-with-resources is used, nothing should leak.